# Uncaught TypeError: r is not a function at index.js:1

Tags: javascript, html, laravel

Laravel Project on Virtual Dedicated Server. After building with `npm run production` I'm opening page via Chrome and see only blank page. Console showed me this error. 
I'm tryed to add some plugins in webpack.mix.js, like 'babel-polyfill' and no result.
Laravel framework 5.4.36
npm version 3.10.10

Here is my app.blade.php

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta
            name="viewport"
            content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=0, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1"
    >

    <!-- CSRF Token -->
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">

    <title>{{ config('app.name', 'Laravel') }}</title>

    <!-- Styles -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ elixir('css/app.css') }}">

    <!-- Scripts -->
    <script>
        window.Laravel = <?php echo json_encode([
                'csrfToken' => csrf_token(),
        ]); ?>
    </script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="react-container"></div>

<!-- Scripts -->
<script>
    var MapInstance;
</script>

<script src="{{ mix('js/app/manifest.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ mix('js/app/vendor.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ mix('js/app/index.js') }}"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

and my webpack.mix.js

```js
let mix = require('laravel-mix');


mix
  .react('resources/assets/js/app/index.jsx', 'public/js/app')
   
  .sass('resources/assets/sass/app.scss', 'public/css')
  .sass('resources/assets/sass/start.scss', 'public/css')
  .copy('node_modules/material-design-lite/material.min.js', 'public/vendor/material.min.js')
  .copy('node_modules/material-design-lite/material.min.js.map', 'public/vendor/material.min.js.map')
  .copy('node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js', 'public/vendor/jquery.min.js')
  .sourceMaps()
  .browserSync('ap.dev');

if (mix.inProduction()) {
  mix.version();
}
```

Comment: Does it work with `npm run dev`? If not what's the error message?

Comment: With `npm run dev` it's compilled succesfullly. In Chrome Console i have now: Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function at materialize.js:7581

Comment: Have you tried changing the import order so that jQuery is before material.js? As in put the third `copy` before first.

Comment: Still have same error

Answer (score 0):

You have to add JQuery before Material in `webpack.mix.js`:

```
// ...

.copy(
    'node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js', 
    'public/vendor/jquery.min.js'
)
.copy(
    'node_modules/material-design-lite/material.min.js',
    'public/vendor/material.min.js'
)
.copy(
    'node_modules/material-design-lite/material.min.js.map',
    'public/vendor/material.min.js.map'
)
```

Comment: Done it. But still have "Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function at materialize.js:7581" with `npm run dev` and "Uncaught TypeError: r is not a function at index.js:1" with `npm run production`

Comment: Hum. You have no `materialize.js` nor `index.js` in your `app.blade.php` file, so I suspect there must be some other files that the ones you shown. Could you search for "materialize.js" in your whole project?

Comment: I think I solved this problem with jQuery. But I have new error: 
Uncaught TypeError: middleware is not a function at applyMiddleware.js:39